# Allow admins to login as other users

Tags: users, admin, user-roles, user-access

My question is about WordPress in general.  How can I give admins the ability to log in and do things that other users can do?

My specific use-case for this is, in WooCommerce, when an admin creates an order via the "Add New Order" page and assigns it to a user the admin can not view the order or complete checkout.  If the admin tries to view the page he gets this error - "This order cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance."

Is there a way to work around this?  I would prefer not to use a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find out what specific capabilities Admin users are missing. Once you know the full list, you can use `add_cap()` to add those capabilities to the Admin users and enable them to do whatever the other roles are doing.

From [Shold I manually add 'cap' to admin role ?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191703/shold-i-manually-add-cap-to-admin-role) -

```
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'cap' );
```

Replace `cap` with one of the capabilities you need to add to admin users. Copy and paste that second line, and add each additional capability separately.

Comment: Thank you!  I found the correct capability, "pay_for_order", added that and it works great.  $role->add_cap('pay_for_order');